# Software for controlling Windows 7 PC from Linux Mint over WLAN

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking, software-rec, remote-access

I have two computers one running Linux Mint and other running Windows 7. I want to be able to control the Windows PC using Linux Mint. They are generally connected over LAN or Wifi using a router.

I want the software to be one which shows notifications when someone is connected to it and not one's which are silent and are used by some people for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many options, all free: *vnc* is surely one of them. There are many programs implementing vnc as both server and client, and they can be freely mixed.

You may look up [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/installing-removing/windows)  or [tightvncserver](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) as a server (the one running on the Windows pc), and to the same programs or others like them (vncviewer, x11vnc, remmina, krdc,  ...) as a client.

Alternatively, you may use RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol), the protocol invented by Microsoft to allow sessions between pcs natively, which is simpler since this does not require setting up a server on a Windows machine, all you have to do is to allow remote sessions (the instructions on how to do this depend on Windows version, you may just Google *Windows allow Remote Desktop connections*). In this case, a good client for Linux is [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try some vnc software, there are a few available for free. Head over to [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com) or [RealVNC](http://realvnc.com)

Comment: Team viewer is not really a good choice here because they route the traffic through their servers. Waste of bandwidth. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have not seen it since a few years(i mean teamviewer) but there used to be an option for using it over local network.

Comment: According to the documentation it will automatically switch to the best direct connection. So **only* if there is **no direct connection possible** between the two computers, traffic will run through the Teamviewer proxy. Otherwise only the initial communication to establish a direct connection is through the Teamviewer-server after which a direct connection is made between the two computers for the actual remote-control.

Answer (score 1):

Enable [remote desk top in windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/)

Then you can use [rdesktop from terminal](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=824710)

eg :- rdesktop 10.4.0.16